# Parsing JSP page, an error notifies well-formedness violation

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, glassfish, java-ee-6

I've got a JSP page. The technologies that I use to write/display it are the following:

- Glassfish 3 (based on Java EE 6)
- Eclipse EE Kepler IDE
- JDK v7

Here comes the page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<% @page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> <center>506</center></h1>
<p/>
<h3>My fancy cat has been caught</h3>
<%
out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
%>

</body>
</html
```

The error occurs on the following line:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

The IDE says:

- XML document is not well-formed due to a parsing error
- The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

If I pass the document to the XML validator:`http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/`, it reports that:

- The markup in the document preceding root element must be well-formed.
- And that the error occurs on the `%` character. Although, it says that the column is number 3. Yet, looking at the document, the column appears to be at number 2 (no space in front of line). The other validator reports the same thing, in terms of column number.

The HTML/JSP document is XML constrained, yet it is not completely XML document, and I assume that is why the validator does not recognize the JSP syntax.

The other thing, is that, the next error occurs on the following line:

```
<%
out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
%>
```

The IDE again complains that, on this character, `%`:

- The content of elements must consists of well-formed character data or markup.

In fact, when I execute the page on the `Glassfish app server`, it displays the contents correctly.
The same error occurs even if I change the app server to `Glassfish 4` (based on Java EE 7).
In addition to that, if I generate the JSP page from the template (available at the IDE), the same error, at the top, reoccurs.

If I type simply the HTML page, the error does not appear. For some reasons the IDE does not accept the JSP syntax.

I need to get fixed it, because, as long this error occurs, I cannot use contents assistant. Which is very helpful working with the page.

Any ideas, what might be the cause of this err?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I come up with the solution. I've replaced the IDE with a fresh install, and the problems have disappeared.
The only things that worked out for me on the previous IDE, is that, if you want to use the `<jsp:scriplet>` in a JSP page you need the following name-space on your root: `xmlns:jsp="http://j‌​ava.sun.com/JSP/Page"‌`.

Moving forward...

Answer (score 0):

You have either to remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` header from your file, or use `<jsp:scriptlet> ... your code ... </jsp:scriptlet>` instead of `<% ... your code ... %>` syntax.

I would recommend the first option, as using XML syntax brings some other limitations (e.g. you have to use `&amp;&amp;` instead of `&&` in conditions etc.).

Comment: So, yeah, I removed the XML declaration line. Yet, the problem persists. If I surround code by the `<jsp:scriplet>` I get this: `The prefix "jsp" for element "jsp:scriplet" is not bound`. If I generate the JSP from template as (html), with no XML declaration, still I get the same err. Can this be a cause by some (mis)configuration on Eclipse?

Comment: Your root element also requires `xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"` if it's meant to be a JSP. All prefixes need to be mapped to namespaces.

Comment: Ok, the addition of the name-space has solved a sub-problem. The problem is that having the following line of definition, at the very top of the JSP page:`<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`, the well-formednes problem still exists. And I would like to use scriplets, etc., in the following way `<%` as well. At this time the IDE raises the errs. Don't you think that, even after generating JSP (HTML) document from the template which comes instantly with the errs, it's something not right?